# what is the meaning of following definition?

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to javascript and start learning from w3schools website. I'm not able to understand what the following line means. Can anyone please explain this with example?

> You can only use document.write in the HTML output. If you use it
>   after the document has loaded (e.g. in a function), the whole document
>   will be overwritten.

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. Also see [ask]

Comment: As a side node, you may want to take a look at this site: http://www.w3fools.com/

Comment: @gnat this is my first question but sure next time i will follow your advice and instruction given in the link.. and by the way thanx for ur advice... :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two moments where JavaScript may be executed:

- When the browser is parsing HTML. Example:

  ```
  ...
  <div>
      alert('Hello World!');
  </div>
  ```
- When the page is already parsed and shown. Example:

  ```
  ...
  <a href="onlick:alert('Hello World!');">Click me please</a>
  ```

`document.write()` has a different behavior for those two cases. In the first one, it will simply insert content within the HTML. In the second case, it will override the whole page.

Example:

```
...
<div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    document.write('Hello World!');
    </script>
</div>
```

produces:

```
...
<div>
    Hello World!
</div>
```

while:

```
...
<div>
    <a href="onlick:document.write('Hello World!');">Click me please</a>
</div>
```

Produces:

```
Hello World!
```

Also note that:

- The statement you quoted is incorrect, as it is often the case with w3schools (if you want high quality documentation, use for example a [similar explanation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.write) on Mozilla Developer Network. The incorrectness is that the quote talks about functions, which has nothing to do with the actual subject. The example from MDN shows very well why the quote is wrong.
- `document.write()` is, among other features such as `alert()`, not very useful and very rarely used in *real* websites. If you want to change the content of a part of a page, you'll rather use `innerHTML` property.
- you shouldn't use w3schools, as stated in the comment above.

Comment: While `document.write()` is seldom used when building websites, it's used extensively to insert third party tracking widgets and advertisements into pages.

Comment: w3schools really rather sucks, but I'm not aware of anywhere else as comprehensive for low barrier to entry HTML/CSS, which is very unfortunate because I'm never sure where else to send them.